# What will Most Effect in Next Life Done Good or Bad?

Tags: rebirth, life

If some person when he live's on earth His doing 50% good & 50% Bad things (theatrically). after he died what will Happen to him in next life. 1st will he effected with his good things he done in Past or bad things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In balance of probability his last though may be 50:50 good or bad. Therefore there is a 50:50 chance the next birth will be good or bad but more biased towards the bad as there always decency that more bad through arise as you minds have the unwholesome roots. Also the action you did near the end may have a significant influence over that happens. Also in this life you might have done 50:50 good and bad but who knows what proportion of Karma you have from previous lives. In absence of a proximate to death or powerful Karma from this life giving arise there might be a chance a Karma from a part life and deciding the final moment. Also if what was done was done low level of volition this might affect the results, e.g., some may give for publicity than benevolent intentions. So it is very difficult to say what the chances are.

Comment: How do you know this is true?

Comment: Only a Buddha will know for sure, as Karma is only fully comprehended by a Fully Enlightened Buddha.

Answer (score 1):

There are five subjects Buddha has stated that cannon be fully understood except by a Buddha.

- Buddha
- Citta
- Kamma
- Loka
- (...)

So one might argue that it really cannot be told with certainty which kamma will take precedence or carry more weight in the next birth.

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of question is very speculative. The Buddha always stressed that thinking/worrying about future and past should be avoided. Instead it would be wise to examine the present.

Answer (score 0):

Buddha said a chance of devas, humans, hungry ghosts, animals to be reborn in heaven or human realms is slim.  He compared it to dust on the tip of his finger nails with respect to great earth. However, There are many ways to beat the odds.
And notice that Buddha did not say that about beings in hell.  It is possible (IMO) that beings in hell have no chance to come straight from there to heaven or earth.  They might have to work their way up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on three things.
 If one has big enough karma either good or bad to carry through afterlife, it will surely be carried through.
 If no such big or remarkable karma, the last moment recall what one regularly or frequently done karma which is passed over to immediate afterlife.
If no two above is in effect, the very last moment karma reflection will have its effect.
So it is not to question 50:50.